# Read JSON file directly from google storage (using Cloud Functions)

Tags: node.js, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage

I created a function that extracts a specific attribute from a JSON file, but this file was together with the function in Cloud Functions. In this case, I was simply attaching the file and was able to refer to a specific attribute:

```
const jsonData = require('./data.json');
const result = jsonData.responses[0].fullTextAnnotation.text;

return result;
```

Ultimately, I want to read this file directly from cloud storage and here I have tried several solutions, but without success. How can I read a JSON file directly from google storage so that, as in the first case, I can read its attributes correctly?

Comment: There are numerous tutorials and examples in many languages for reading files in Cloud Storage. Show what you tried, the code, and errors.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To clearly answer the question: **you can't!**

You need to download the file locally first, and then process it. You can't read it directly from GCS.

With Cloud Functions you can only store file in the `/tmp` directory, it's the only one writable. In addition, it's an in-memory file system, that means several things:

- The size is limited by the memory set up to the Cloud Function. The memory space is shared between your app memory footprint and your file storage in `/tmp` (you won't be able to download a file of 10Gb for example)
- The memory is lost when the instance goes down and
- All the Cloud Functions instances have their own memory space. You can't share the files between all the Cloud Functions
- The `/tmp` directory isn't cleaned between 2 functions invocation (on the same instance). Think to cleanup yourselves this directory.

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned in the comment the Cloud Storage API allows you to do many things through API. Here's an example from [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/samples/storage-download-file#storage_download_file-nodejs) on how to download a file from Cloud Storage for your reference.

```
/**
 * TODO(developer): Uncomment the following lines before running the sample.
 */
// The ID of your GCS bucket
// const bucketName = 'your-unique-bucket-name';

// The ID of your GCS file
// const fileName = 'your-file-name';

// The path to which the file should be downloaded
// const destFileName = '/local/path/to/file.txt';

// Imports the Google Cloud client library
const {Storage} = require('@google-cloud/storage');

// Creates a client
const storage = new Storage();

async function downloadFile() {
  const options = {
    destination: destFileName,
  };

  // Downloads the file
  await storage.bucket(bucketName).file(fileName).download(options);

  console.log(
    `gs://${bucketName}/${fileName} downloaded to ${destFileName}.`
  );
}

downloadFile().catch(console.error);
```